# Get a change event when the value bound to TextProperty is changed for Decended TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, wcf-binding

I have my own custom TextBox class (call it `MyCustomTextBox`). In part it helps me handle scans from a barcode reader.

Part of what I need for this to work is a way to capture when the value bound to TextProperty changes.

Note: I am not looking for the "TextChanged" event or any kind of event that relates to a key press (except when that key press updates the source).

Here is an example:

I need an event (in `MyCustomTextBox`) that will fire ONLY when the underlying value (CustomerId) gets changed.

Note: The actual TextProperty gets changed every time a key press happens.  But the Source is not updated until later (depending on your UpdateSourceTrigger setting).  The TextProperty changes too frequently for what I am trying to do.  So attaching to it will not help me.

Is there any way to attach to the value under the TextProperty?

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get change events for value bound to TextProperty for a decendant of TextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678632/get-change-events-for-value-bound-to-textproperty-for-a-decendant-of-textbox)

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you need to hook up 2 events though

```
        <TextBox Name="Fred" Text="{Binding Foo, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" TargetUpdated="Fred_TargetUpdated" SourceUpdated="Fred_SourceUpdated">
```

TargetUpdated event will get fired when something other than the textbox changes the underlying property (and when it first binds) eg. some method in your VM say

Sourceupdated event will get fired when your textbox updates its binding eg on lost focus

Comment: This does not fire everytime `Foo` is changed.  ie: `Foo=value;` `(PropertyChanged("Foo");`.  It only fires when `Foo` is changed by the TextBox.

Comment: TargetUpdated fires for me when thr underlying property changes.  For example if I put a button on my screen and on the click event do Foo = "whatever" the TargetUpdated event on the textbox fires.  Are we talking about the same thing? do you have INotify working etc?